# Unique IDs in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, uuid

So I am working on a fairly small script for the company I work at the help us manage our servers better. I don't use MySQL too often though so I am a bit confused on what would be the best path to take.

I am doing something like this...

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Servers
    (
        MachineID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(MachineID),
        FirstName varchar(32),
        LastName varchar(32),
        Datacenter TINYINT(1),
        OperatingSystem TINYINT(1),
        HostType TINYINT(1)
    )";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
check ($result);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Datacenter
    (
        DatacenterID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(DatacenterID),
        Name varchar(32),
        Location varchar(32)
    )";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
check ($result);
```

Basically inside the Servers table, I will be storing the index of an entry in another table. My concern is that if we remove one of those entries, it will screw up the auto incremented indexes and potentially cause a lot of incorrect data.

To explain better, lets say the first server I add, the Datacenter value is 3 (which is the DatacenterID), and we remove the id 1 (DatacenterID) Datacenter at a later time.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: How could the autoincremented indexes "screw up"? When you remove Datacenter 1, the former Datacenter 3 is still known with id 3. You may have some server in your table that are connected to the removed datacenter 1, but you should fix that in your script.

Comment: Removing the record with id=1 won't affect the record with id=3 at all.  Perhaps I don't understand the question properly? (EDIT: Yeah, what @Stephan B said.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto increment only has an effect on inserting new rows into a table. So you insert three records into database and they get assigned ids of 1, 2, and 3. Later you delete id 1, but the records at id 2 and 3 are unchanged. This says nothing of any of the server records that might be trying to reference the database id 1 record though that is now missing.

Comment: Taking off to sleep, won't let me accept the answer but I will get it when I wake up.

Comment: It's implicit in @Paul's answer, and probably obvious anyway, but just to be clear: the auto-indexer won't recycle values.  The next record will still be 4.

Comment: auto_increment values are stored separately in the table, and are remembered so that unless you override that stored value, you'll never get a recycled value until the increment exceeds the size limit of the field you're incrementing on.

Answer (score 1):

as said by paul, it is safe to remove old row and add another new one later. The auto incremental index won't be affected by deletion.

But I would suggest instead of removing them, simply add a column 'status' and set 0, implying they are no longer in use, to keep any possible record in db.

Answer (score 0):

Servers.Datacenter should be an INT, too, as you would store the DataCenterID in this field. Then, nothing will be mixed up when you remove some Datacenter from the second table.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove in the way you suggest nothing will happen. auto-increment will just add the next highest number in sequence whenever a new record is added and so will not affect any previous records.

Hope that helps.